# namespace SIFT error in making opencv and opencv_contrib 4.3.0 (under ubuntu)

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, cmake, opencv-contrib

the error broke during the make period

this is the procedure before the error came out

1.download the source code from github of opencv and opencv_contrib 4.3.0

2.creat a dir under opencv source code dir name **opencv_contrib**

3.enter the build dir and enter the code

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules ..
```

some of the files to download while cmake didn't download but I manually download those and all of the fail-to-download files are copied to the required route

then begin to *make*

```
make -j7
```

error break while making

```
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_xfeatures2d
[ 90%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_xfeatures2d.dir/test/test_detectors.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object modules/gapi/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gapi.dir/test/internal/gapi_transactions_test.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object modules/gapi/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gapi.dir/test/own/conc_queue_tests.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_xfeatures2d.dir/test/test_features2d.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_xfeatures2d.dir/perf/perf_surf.ocl.cpp.o
/home/wang/Documents/opencv-4.3.0/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/test/test_features2d.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void opencv_test::{anonymous}::Features2d_SIFTHomographyTest_regression_Test::Body()’:
/home/wang/Documents/opencv-4.3.0/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/test/test_features2d.cpp:366:88: error: ‘SIFT’ has not been declared
 TEST(Features2d_SIFTHomographyTest, regression) { CV_DetectPlanarTest test("SIFT", 80, SIFT::create()); test.safe_run(); }
                                                                                        ^~~~
/home/wang/Documents/opencv-4.3.0/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/test/test_features2d.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void opencv_test::{anonymous}::Features2d_SIFT_using_mask_regression_Test::Body()’:
/home/wang/Documents/opencv-4.3.0/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/test/test_features2d.cpp:435:39: error: ‘SIFT’ has not been declared
     FeatureDetectorUsingMaskTest test(SIFT::create());
```

reference websites

https://www.cnblogs.com/fx-blog/p/8213704.html

https://blog.csdn.net/u011736771/article/details/85960300

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more information about your issue, including steps you took to produce the error. Are you following a tutorial or some kind? If so, please link to it in your question.

Comment: thank you for giving me that advice I have added more details in the body

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the 4.3.0 release, SIFT was moved out of xfeatures2d but I dont think it was inserted in the main branch for the 4.3.0 release. Just download the master (development) branch and the problem is solved